# What does a perfect Community Wiki Q&A template look like?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, instant-self-answer

I joined Stack Overflow for the main purpose of sharing information in a Q&A style. Over the years, I can't help but wonder if the Q&A I posted as Community Wiki is serving its purposes as a simple way of sharing information, or it's getting discouraged just from the title alone?

To that end, I would like to know what the ideal Community Wiki Q&A template format that I can use looks like, so when I encountered a problem, knew the solution, and wasn't able to find relevant questions about the problem on Stack Overflow, I will then be able to write it out according to the template, and be done with it.

Comment: Asking good questions (and posting good answers) isn't a simple as following a template.  It's much harder than that.

Comment: As Servy says, it's not as easy as following a template. However, you can use the [ask] page as a guide for the Q and the [answer] page as a guide for the A. Really, the way to make a good Community Wiki self-answered question... Is to make a really good question (regardless of answer quality or existance) and answer it with a really good answer (which addresses the question, has a clear explanation, etc.) If you can do that, then you've likely made a high-quality, useful Q&A.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting discouraged just from the title alone"?

Comment: @Suragch I guess they mean "here's something called Community Wiki, I'm wary of using it if I don't understand what a Community Wiki is, so is there some simple form that I can fill in for question and answer so that it is a true Community Wiki". Since a self-answered question need not be Community Wiki, it that aspect may be an accidental diversion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such template, since:

- Asking good questions is hard
- Answering questions is hard, too.

So, there isn't a silver bullet solution for self answered questions. Just ask a good, well researched question that *others can answer* and post your answer there.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, only one really good true Community Wiki (and also canonical) Q&A pair comes to mind: [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/2415822)

I'm sure there are others, but since I'm mainly an iOS programmer and this is a common question that is asked, this is the one I use as a dupe target the most.

There can be no "perfect" CW Q&A pair, but I can think of a a few good properties one would have.

- It provides background of the issue, not just why it occurs on how to solve it.  In the Swift example, there are countless ways of unwrapping an optional improperly.  This CW pair goes into detail about language semantics and the type system of Swift to provide clarity and background.
- It is comprehensive.  While impossible (and unnecessary) to list every type that can be unwrapped improperly, this answer goes though all possible scenarios (even non-code ones that involve nib loading and Interface Builder).
- It is constantly updated, not only be the OP, but by other users.  As the Swift language evolves, there could be new ways this error can occur.  These are added to the answer as new language features are introduced.
- It is the de facto dupe target.  iOS and Swift dupe hammer holders and other power users of the tag know to use this post as a dupe target, because they know it is the go-to answer for these types of questions.

And lastly, the author chose to make it CW.  There used to be quite a few Q&A pairs on this topic, and this CW canonical would not have been possible if jtbandes did not chose to make his CW (it wasn't always), and with the help of other users and moderators, merge content from the duplicate Q&A pairs into this answer.