# What is the proper way to write proposed FAQ questions and answers?

Tags: support, meta, canonical

A few months back I posted a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343113/are-questions-about-the-internals-of-the-linux-kernel-on-topic-for-stack-overflow) about whether or not questions about the Linux kernel are on topic here. It seems like it's something that a reasonable number of people are confused about, and it generated a really superb [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343114/4032703) from Tim Post.

I'm curious about whether it would be worthwhile to create a proposed FAQ about whether questions like that (questions that aren't strictly about specific code but *are* about the internals of an operating system, device drivers, etc.) are on topic.

Hopefully this question isn't too broad (please comment letting me know if it is), but how would I go about turning this into a proposed FAQ? Would I have to do anything besides generalizing it to all operating systems (rather than just being a Linux question)? Is it even worth proposing a FAQ about this in the first place?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq-proposed/info

Comment: related (probably not a duplicate): [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276010/839601)

Comment: [Martijn gave me some advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287995/comments-timestamps-can-give-away-a-review-audit?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment165246_287996) when I was interested in create a faq-proposed question.

Comment: Also very related: [What does a perfect Community Wiki Q&A template look like?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339030/2415822) (although not FAQ specific)

Comment: Ironically, this could well be a duplicate of [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225); see the section there about how to add posts to the FAQ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters not 100% because the OP asks *first* if it is worthwhile to create the faq-proposed, so we're not yet at the faq-proposed step. But I'm happy to call it *muggenziften* if you say so ...

Comment: @rene: which is why I stopped short of closing it outright.

Comment: I don't really see why this needs to be a FAQ. It's already got semi-official status by virtue of it having been (A) answered by a community manager, and (B) gotten the support of the community, so if you want to refer someone to it, just point them directly to the question. It is otherwise unlikely that anyone will go searching for this kind of specificity in the FAQ.

Comment: Note: Tim didn't say that every linux kernel question is on topic, he said "it (would) take a programmer to understand answers to this". Changing the ulimits isn't on topic, unless you need to be a programmer to understand it.

Comment: @CodyGray I do agree that people probably wouldn't search for something so specific. I'm wondering if it would be possible to generalize it, though. For example, I ran into a question about a detail of the Windows operating system internals that had been voted off-topic as not a programming question, so obviously this applied to that case.

Comment: Link? Be happy to re-open that one for you if I agree. (As for the *actual* answer to your question, you'd just create a new, more generalized Meta question, and add the [meta-tag:faq-proposed] tag.)